# Как поставить русский язык в консоле на ввод

Tags: c++, консоль

У меня проблема - нормально не отображается русский язык, а так же не принимаются русские литеры. Как можно это исправить? SETLOCALE нормально не работает.

Comment: поищите на этом сайте - эти вопросы обсуждались 1000 раз

Comment: Приведите пример.

Comment: Добавьте информации о вашей ОС.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй

```
system("chcp 1251 > nul");
```

Это команда работает на ввод и на вывод.